# How to add outline to a image box in the Canvas Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 3D Game in Unity with an inventory. Each item in the inventory is displayed as pictures in the Canvas. I want, when the user clicks on the item (the picture), it to highlight, indicating that it is currently selected.

So, my question is, how can I add an outline to that image? It is a simple problem, but I really couldn't find it's solution. I tried also the outline asset in the unity store, which I am using for normal 3D Objects but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an outline image to your slot prefab.

Then you can activate/deactivate it in script
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSTmk.png)